# Replace pre-set SheetID and SheetName with user input through an interface?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have deployed an add-on (code below) that allows me to pull rows from a Spreadsheet and create/update options on a Google Form. The code itself works perfectly. I’m looking to learn how I can upgrade it to the next level. I would like to make it so the SheetID and SheetName can be pasted in through a sidebar or pop-up window for users who aren’t me. I know it is possible to do something like this, but I’m very lost on what to add. It might also be easier to incorporate the window that generates the user’s Google Drive, and from there they select the Sheet, select the SheetName, and then go. Additionally, if there’s a way to make it so they only have to run this set-up one time for it to work on every Form it’s installed on, that would be awesome. I know I’m asking for a lot, but even a direction to point me in terms of documentation, words to look up, etc. is helpful. Thank you in advance!

```
function openForm(e)
{
  populateQuestions();
}

function populateQuestions() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var googleSheetsQuestions = getQuestionValues();
  var itemsArray = form.getItems();
  itemsArray.forEach(function(item){
    googleSheetsQuestions[0].forEach(function(header_value, header_index) {
      if(header_value == item.getTitle())
      {
        var choiceArray = [];
        for(j = 1; j < googleSheetsQuestions.length; j++)
        {
          (googleSheetsQuestions[j][header_index] != '') ? choiceArray.push(googleSheetsQuestions[j][header_index]) : null;
        }
        item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(choiceArray);
        // If using Dropdown Questions use line below instead of line above.
        //item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choiceArray);
      }
    });     
  });
}

function getQuestionValues() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById('1QeckPxMYSYGMkZ-QggY76u03N1qBKBGL2UEMcUvu7sM');
  var questionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  var returnData = questionSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return returnData;
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer that might help you. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @bysshe, Giselle's answer seems to be a great way to achieve what you needed, did it work for you?  See: [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it, this is just a sample so it’s very basic. First, you need to create an HTML file inside the Apps script editor.

Using this option:
Note - I named mine page.

[image: add HTML page]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <script>
        function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().populateQuestions(formObject);
        } 
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Please add your Google Sheet information</h2>

    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <label for="sheetID">Add your Sheet ID:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="sheetID" name="sheetID" value="Google Sheet ID"><br>
      <label for="sheetName">Add Sheet Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="sheetName" name="sheetName" value="e.g. Sheet1"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside the  tag I created a function called `handleFormSubmit` which will create an object with the `Sheet ID` and the `Sheet name` submitted by the end user.

I didn’t know how to make the form close once the user hit submit, so I added an extra close button. You can search for a better option. The Sidebar menu looks like this:

[image: side menu]

Back to the `Code.gs` I created an onOpen menu:

```
function onOpen() {
  //you can change the names of the menu
  FormApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('formTest')
    .addItem('Show menu', 'showSidebar')
    .addToUi();
}
```

[image: Open menu] => [image: show sidebar]

Also created a function to call the sidebar:

```
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page')
      .setTitle('Google Sheet data');
  FormApp.getUi() 
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Lastly, I modify the function `populateQuestions` and the `getQuestionValues` to store and pass the values from the form to the Apps Script.

From the `populateQuestions` function, I only modify this part from:

```
function populateQuestions() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var googleSheetsQuestions = getQuestionValues();
```

To:

```
function populateQuestions(formObject) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var googleSheetsQuestions = getQuestionValues(formObject);
```

And the `getQuestionValues` function from:

```
function getQuestionValues() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById('1QeckPxMYSYGMkZ-QggY76u03N1qBKBGL2UEMcUvu7sM');
  var questionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  var returnData = questionSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return returnData;
}
```

To:

```
function getQuestionValues(formObject) {
  // create a property services to store the data in the document
  // so it can continue to call it even after closing an opening the form
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();

  // create variables for the document properties
  let sheet_ID = documentProperties.setProperty('sheet ID',formObject.sheetID);
  let sheet_name = documentProperties.setProperty('Sheet Name',formObject.sheetName);

  // pass the new variables to the Apps Script
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_ID);
  var questionSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  var returnData = questionSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return returnData;
}
```

**Reference:**

- [HTML Service - Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)
- [Properties Service - Saving data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#saving_data)
- [Custom sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)
- [HTML forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)